# Change Action Bar Background

Tags: android, android-studio, android-styles, android-navigation

I'm trying to change the action bar color.

[image]

Does anyone knows how it's possible?

Thanks!!

Comment: dude, check out this answer; 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26477840/change-android-5-0-actionbar-color

Comment: Yes! http://stackoverflow.com/a/27469309/3768514

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Google page: https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#ColorPalette

I added a style propriert inside my main theme:

```
<item name="colorPrimary">#6876c5</item>
```

and it did work!